# FB.getLoginStatus() and local development

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've thoroughly searched the questions here and tried all kinds of suggestions. Nothing actually worked.

I am trying to call Facebook's SDK FB.getLoginStatus() in my local dev environment, but it never returns. What I already tried:

1. Reviewed my FB App setting to make sure that the currect URLs were configured in all fields (Site URL and Canvas URL and they are correct ([http://localhost], [http://localhost/facebook], respectively).
2. Tried to develop in my QA environment, changing the URL Fields in my FB app settings accordingly
3. Instead of calling FB.getLoginStatus(), subscribed to "auth.authResponseChange" and used status : true in FB.init()

My app is in sandbox mode.
Nothing worked... the only way things worked was under HTTPS in production with Sandbox mode disabled.

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't work"? What are you seeing?

Comment: What I mean by doesn't work is that FB.getLoginStatus() never returns.